# How do games detect lost focus (such as opening notification pane) on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

For example in game Asphalt 9, when the player swiping down the notification, the game is paused.

I have tried onPause, but it only fired when I switch to another app / activity. It doesn't detect something like opening the notification pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override *[onWindowFocusChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean))* method of activity. It will loose focus when user open notification bar or some system dialog show up.